# Why can I not collect coins and I get an error message

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and C# as well but I do have a small understanding of it because I've learnt python. At the moment I've run into an error, I'm trying to make a coin collection system and also the players movement in one script simply because it seems neater that way and easier to play audio.

The error comes up on this line, `[SerializeField] private Transform groundcheck = null;` (it's used so the player can jump over and over). I have a theory that maybe I just need to change the collision value, but other then no clue what I need to do to change this error.

Full Script:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour

{
     [SerializeField] private Transform groundcheck = null;

    private bool jumpkeywaspressed;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private Rigidbody rigibodycomponent;
    public AudioSource coincollect;
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigibodycomponent = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            jumpkeywaspressed = true;
    
    
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigibodycomponent.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput * 3, rigibodycomponent.velocity.y,0);

        if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundcheck.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (jumpkeywaspressed)
        {
            rigibodycomponent.AddForce(Vector3.up * 5, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            jumpkeywaspressed = false;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == 6)
        {
            coincollect.Play();
            ScoreManager.sManger.IncreaseScore(1);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

I also have another script which is used to increase the score but I don't think it effects my error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: sorry I thought I wrote it down, the error is the NullReferenceException saying null is not accepted

Comment: Which line is it happening on?

Comment: If i had to guess the error is on this line `if (Physics.OverlapSphere(groundcheck.position, 0.1f).Length == 1)`

Comment: It doesn't seem you are setting `groundcheck` to a value anywhere besides the initial `null` value. When you try to call `groundcheck.position` it is trying to get the position of a null, which doesn't exist.

If you actually are setting `groundcheck` somewhere, then you aren't setting its position to a value.

Comment: Make sure you've selected a Transform on this component in the Inspector.